# ReactJS - Transfer data to child component and get back data from component click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a parent component, it will render a Breadcrumbs. The code as below:

```
<Breadcrumbs urlPath={this.state.urlPath} />
```

And breadcrumbs are rendered as below:

```
   <Breadcrumbs aria-label="breadcrumb">
        {urlArr.map((url, index) => 
            <Link key={index} color="inherit" href="/" >
                { url }
            </Link>
        )}
        <Typography color="textPrimary">{selected}</Typography>
   </Breadcrumbs>
```

I want the click on link event in the breadcrumbs to send the {url} back to the parent component.

Is there any way to do that? Thanks everyone!

Comment: The second code is inside Breadcrumb component (child component).

Comment: What is "urlArr" variable?

Comment: It is the urlPath after cutting: var urlArr = this.props.urlPath.split("/");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can pass function as prop to the breadcrumb component like so

**Parent.jsx:**

```
onBreadcrumbSelect(url) {
    console.log(url);
}

render() {
    return (
        ... other components ...
        <Breadcrumbs urlPath={this.state.urlPath} onLinkSelect={this.onBreadcrumbSelect.bind(this)} />
    )
```

**Breadcrumb.jsx**

```
   <Breadcrumbs aria-label="breadcrumb">
        {urlArr.map((url, index) => 
            <Link key={index} color="inherit" href="/" onClick={() => this.props.onLinkSelect(url)} >
                { url }
            </Link>
        )}
        <Typography color="textPrimary">{selected}</Typography>
   </Breadcrumbs>
```

This will pass bound function from the parent to breadcrumb. But when you call this function in breadcrumb, it will call the bound function from the parent component.

Answer (score 0):

On your parent, add this function and the `onLinkClick` parameter to your child component:

```
void handleLinkClick(string url){
   /* Do your logic */
}
...
<Breadcrumbs urlPath={this.state.urlPath} onLinkClick={handleLinkClick} />
```

Then adjust your child component:

```
 <Link key={index} color="inherit" href="/" onClick={() => handleLinkClick(url)} >
         { url }
 </Link>
```

Is that what you are trying?